# Match pattern, then replace single character in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have successfully matched an apostrophe occurring betweem letters and numbers only. Within that pattern, I now want to replace only the apostrophe, not the entire matched pattern. The code:

```
import re

content = "MC_MC - 90's"
search = re.sub(r'([A-Za-z0-9]\'[A-Za-z0-9])', '%APOS', content)
print(search)
```

Current output:

```
MC_MC - 9%APOS
```

Desired output:

```
MC_MC - 90%APOSs
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: use positive lookbehind and positive lookahead like this `r"(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])'(?=[A-Za-z0-9])"`

Comment: @VishalSingh Post it as an answer and explain how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use 0 length assertions (also knows as lookaround) for this.

`(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])'(?=[A-Za-z0-9])`

- `(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])` Positive lookbehind to assert `[A-Za-z0-9]` is behind
- `'` matches `'` character literally
- `(?=[A-Za-z0-9])` Positive lookahead to assert `[A-Za-z0-9]` is ahead

```
import re

content = "MC_MC - 90's"
print(re.sub(r"(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])'(?=[A-Za-z0-9])", "%APOS", content))
```

**Output:**

```
MC_MC - 90%APOSs
```

Answer (score 3):

Id'use two capture groups and use them in your replacement:

```
(?i)([a-z\d])'([a-z\d])
```

and replace with: `\1%APOS\2`. See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/KntrHx/1)

---

- `(?i)` - Trigger case-insensitive matching for remainder of pattern.
- `([a-z\d])` - A 1st capture group to match a alphanumeric char.
- `'` - A literal apostrophe.
- `([a-z\d])` - A 2nd capture group to match a alphanumeric char.

---

An Python example:

```
import re
content = "MC_MC - 90's"
search = re.sub(r"(?i)([a-z\d])'([a-z\d])", r'\1%APOS\2', content)
print(search)
```

Prints: `MC_MC - 90%APOSs`